# Apple Sign In Email Popup

Tags: ios, swift

I have to debug the Hide/Show Popup in the Apple SignIn process in the Application, but it comes only once I have deleted the App.

Is there any way out to get the Starting Popup options of Hide/Show email again?

Thanks.

Comment: Facing same behaviour from few days, couldn't find any solution yet. Please post answer if anyone knows. Thanks :)

Comment: @SimranjitSingh Please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting back starting popup you have to remove your application from **Apps Using Your Apple ID** which is in Settings app.

Please follow this step in your iPhone to find the path.

1) Open the Settings app, then tap [your name].

2) Tap Password & Security

3) Tap Apps Using Your Apple ID.

For more info: `https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT210426`

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer.

Comment: Happy to help you!